# How to set an element to a default condition (hide ()) and when clicked (show())

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent

Say I have a left-side chat bar with chat users. Each user has their image (much like Facebook's chat)and is clickable to open a chat box to start chatting away.

Here's my code:

```
$('.msg_wrap').hide();
$('.msg_box').hide();
    $('.chat_user').click(function() {          
        $('.msg_wrap').show();
        $('.msg_box').show();
}
```

I know this is wrong but what I want to do here is when the page loads for the first time, all the chatboxes to be hidden (hide ()). It is not until I click on a chat user (.chat_user) that a pop up/chat box appears (show()). How do I fix this code? Do I have to create a function?

Comment: I don't think you have provided enough information.  You illustrate three CSS classes called ".msg_wrap", ".msg_box" and ".chat_user" but don't describe how they relate to anything.  You code says "When a click event happens on an element with a class of 'chat_user' then execute the show method on elements with classes of 'msg_wrap' or 'msg_box'.  This code is fine ... I don't think we know what you want.

Answer (score 0):

A quick thought on a solution.

First.  Set the elements ('.msg_wrap') and ('.msg_box') to hidden in your html and kill your first two lines of code.  I am not sure what those elements specifically are, but, for example, if they were div tags it would look something like:

```
<div hidden class="msg_wrap">
```

Second.  I am not sure if you are saying that the code currently isn't working on page load.  It looks like you are missing a ) at the end and also you can update to the following so that it gets executed on page load.

```
$(function(){
   $('.chat_user').click(function() {          
        $('.msg_wrap').show();
        $('.msg_box').show();
    }); 
});
```

This is jquery shorthand for $( document ).ready().

Also, if you want the msg_wrap and msg_box elements to toggle between being hidden and shown you can use the toggle() method instead of show().

Comment: Best answer. Actually didn't need the "$(function(){" and end bracket after all.  Just the code inside the function, which I had in the beginning but got frustrated because it wasn't doing the job. All I needed was just to hide the classes in the html using "<div hidden class="name_of_class>" as you mentioned, then have the click function "$('.chat_user')" show the class. Again thanks for your help, gave me great insight!

Comment: Great to hear.  Would appreciate if you could accept the answer and upvote it.